# Implementing a Set collection using ArrayList

Tags: java, collections

Im having a hard time implementing a set collection using arrayList.
I don't want to use a HashSet. And i would like an someone to explain me please why it is not working

set.java:

```
public class set<E> {
    Set <E> setList;
    ArrayList<E> elementList;

    public set(){

        this.setList = (Set<E>) new ArrayList();

    }

    public set(E[] inputArray){
        super();
        for(E element: inputArray)
            setList.add( element);
    }
```

my main.java:

```
Integer a[]= {4,2,9,2,2,2,52};
set aSet = new set(a);
System.out.println(aSet.toString());
```

i get an error:

```
java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Set
```

Comment: Well actually you are importing `java.util.Set` and your class is calling `set` this is not a good practise, lead to confussion (and you are not following java code conventions). But an ArrayList doesn't implement `Set` interface then it's why you get that error.

Comment: You need also to specify your E by using this : set<Integer> aSet = new <> set(a). Don't use raw types..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot cast  `ArrayList` to `Set`, they are at the same level in inheritance tree (like brothers), Not sure what are you trying to achieve by this

<strike>If you want to create `HashSet` out of `ArrayList` use the constructor</strike>

```
new HashSet<SomeType>(arrayListInstance);
```

as @nacho mentioned, You will need to implement `Set` interface and name your implementation some meaning full name (for example `ListBackedSet` or `ArraySet`)

If you want to create new implementation of Set backed by `ArrayList`, You need to preserve uniqueness property and for that you will have to customize `add()`, `addAll()` and constructors to avoid duplication

Comment: Actually OP says that he don't want to use a `HashSet`

Comment: But it's not bad to mention that he need to `implements Set` interface or extends some `AbstractSet` to make his own implementation. An also call it `set` lead to confusion besides that name even follow java code conventions.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast `ArrayList`  to `Set`.which give exception.
at line

```
this.setList = (Set<E>) new ArrayList();
```